# what is cacheable communications protocol

Tags: rest, http-caching

Might be this is stupid question but i didn't find anything understandable regarding *cacheable communications protocol* .

I am learning REST now. for this i am following [this](http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/what-is-rest.html) tutorial. I am understanding what is REST exactly.

At one place i find REST id stateless, Client-server,  and cacheable communications protocol. I know what is stateless and client server. But i stuck on *cacheable communications protocol*.

I tried to find related this but not getting(or may be you can say understand) anything.

Can any one elaborate *cacheable communications protocol* .

Answer (score 1):

It's not too complicated. A cacheable communications protocol includes accommodating the ability for client-side caching and a set of specifications for when a response to a query can be cached. The HTTP 1.1 protocol is such a protocol and includes an entire section on the rules of the road for caching (see rfc2616 section 13).

In other words, it's a protocol where caching is desirable so it's explicitly designed in.